# Compare strings with middle dot not working in PHP

Tags: php, special-characters, strcmp

I get a string from the database, where it is encoded with `utf8_unicode_ci`. It might contain the *middle dot character* (⋅) and I have to find out using `strcmp`. If I show the string in the HTML directly, the character is displayed without problem but when I do the comparison, the results is not what I expect.

For example:

```
$string = "⋅⋅⋅ This string starts with middle dots";
$result = strcmp(substr($string , 0, 2), "⋅⋅");
```

The results is not 0, as I think should be. The PHP file is saved with UTF-8 encoding. What am I missing here? This happens even if I take the string from a variable instead of the database

Comment: You probably need to use the multibyte functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's substr does not take unicode characters as a single character.

The [dot you're using](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22c5/index.htm) is actually 3 characters, `0xE2 0x8B 0x85`.

So either use mb_substr, or use a different offset:

```
<?php

$string = "⋅⋅⋅ This string starts with middle dots";
$result = strcmp(mb_substr($string , 0, 2), "⋅⋅");

var_dump($result);
```

Or if mb_* functions don't exist:

```
<?php

$string = "⋅⋅⋅ This string starts with middle dots";
$result = strcmp(substr($string , 0, 6), "⋅⋅");

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

use `strpos` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

this returns an int value of the first occurrence of specified character. E.g.:

```
$myStr = '.. this is a string';
$find  = '..';
$pos   = strpos($myStr, $find);

var_dump($pos); //will output 0;
```

if it's not found - it returns false.

Comment: Thanks. I will use `mb_strpos`